# How to ignore padding of parent view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `ScrollView` layout (or other layout type it doesn't mater) which has child views. And this parent layout has `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight`. I want to have this padding set for each child, but sometimes I have exception where I want that child to reach edges of the display completely (for example `TextView` with background color). Is there any way how to allow this to happen? I don't wanna set padding for every single child separately.

Comment: I don't think its possible . There can be some hack solution. U need a set margin on child views .

Answer (score 0):

You told us what you want: "*sometimes a Child shouldn't have to respect its Parent padding*", so the special behaviour should occurs on Children.

The solution is to EXTEND Child's main View in which it chooses its MARGIN by default and then create a "*Child.setNoMargins()*" method that removes them from itself when required.

```
public static class ExtendedTextView extends TextView {
    
    private boolean mHasNoMargins = false;

    public ExtendedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    
    public void setNoMargins() {
        mHasNoMargins = true;
        if (!isInLayout() && isAttachedToWindow()) requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (!mHasNoMargins && (params instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)) {
            ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)params).setMarginStart(20);
            ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)params).setMarginEnd(20);
        }
        super.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

In this way all created "ExtendedTextView" have default Left/Right margins until you call "setNoMargins()".
Obliviously my code works only if parent ViewGroup supports LayoutParams having Margins (most of them).